# how does binding to a service method work?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

In [this first example](http://plnkr.co/edit/u9mjQvdsvuSYTKMEfUwR?p=preview), the the view is updated everytime the return value of the method sessionStatus() of userService changes.

but If a change the `sessionStatus` method like in [the second example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rW4Q7OMSzqVrk9fSBBsE?p=preview) :

```
sessionStatus: function(){
  return Date.now();
},
```

it no longer refreshes "live" in the view. I would expect to see the date in milliseconds progressing in the view.

Is it because [the second example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rW4Q7OMSzqVrk9fSBBsE?p=preview), the value returned by the `sessionStatus` method is changing to fast ? Why isn't it updating the view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is not updating because there is no AngularJS event to cause a digest cycle:

Add a button that has an `ng-click` and the value will update everytime it is clicked:

```
<body ng-app="myServiceModule">
    <div id="simple" ng-controller="MyController">

  <p>I would expect the number bellow to be ticking</p>
    <p>Session Status: {{sessionStatus()}}</p>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="">Update</button>
</body>
```

By clicking on the <kbd>Update</kbd> button, an AngularJS digest cycle gets initiated and the session status updates.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/FuryNqF8ozKyiwaexOja?p=preview).

---

Or use the `$interval` service to initiate a repeating digest cycle:

```
  angular.
   module('myServiceModule', []).
    controller('MyController', function ($scope, $interval, userService) {
      $scope.sessionStatus = function(){
       return userService.sessionStatus();
      };

      $interval(null, 250);

    })
```

In this example, the `$interval` statement starts a digest cycle every 250 milliseconds.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/p0HNFuMmLUn8pfnZWmL8?p=preview)